# Thermistors and their resistance

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electricity, electrical-resistance

I take GCSE physics and I'm having difficulty understanding how resistance and temperature link with one another. I've been taught that the greater a component's temperature, the greater the KE of its ions, the greater the charge disrupting oscillations by the ions, the greater the resistance.

But I've also learnt that a thermistor's resistance decreases the higher the temperature gets. thus far I only know this is because electrons from the valence level move into the conduction band when energy is supplied to the Thermistor, allowing better conduction of charge.

How do both explanations not contradict with one another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a metal the density of mobile charge carriers (electrons) is approximately constant and not much dependent on temperature.
As the temperature is increased the interactions between the lattice ions and the electrons disrupt the passage of the mobile charge carriers (electric current) more.
The resistance of a metal increase as the temperature increase.

For the (nth - negative temperature coefficient) type of thermistor that you have mentioned in your question an increase in the temperature results in the density of mobile charge carriers increasing ie mobile charge carriers are created.
The increase in the density of mobile charge carriers has a larger effect on the resistance of the thermistor than the disruption due to thermal excitation of the lattice.
This results in a decrease in the resistance of a nth thermistor as the temperature increases.

Comment: These “charge carriers” are just electrons in the thermistor’s valence band being promoted to the outer conduction band? And the way your answer included the phrase “the increase in mobile charge carriers has a larger effect on the thermistors resistance than the interactions of lattice ions and their electrons” made it sound as if this happens to every component, except that in others the vibrations of a components atoms increase the resistance of said component more than the creation of charge carriers can decrease it. I thought this was only something that happened to semiconductors

Comment: @UbaidHassan The reason I did not use the electron as the mobile charge carrier is that it can also be holes that transport the charge. For example, see [Wikipedia - Thermistor - Negative Temperature Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor#NTC_(negative_temperature_coefficient))